# Post Async (404) vs post man (401)

Tags: c#, api, system.net.httpwebrequest

So I am trying to call an api end point using postasync

```
client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(Data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")).Result
```

and is using the wrong credential on purpose to test authentication. I am using basic auth. What I am getting back is a `404 Not found` vs the expected `401 (Unauthorized)`. So when I try it on Postman, I am getting the correct response back a `401 (Unauthorized)`. Is this because of how 'PostAsync' works? Are there additional settings I need to turn on. As a reference, I am also making a delete call

```
await client.DeleteAsync(uri)
```

using the wrong credentials and I am correctly getting a `401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: Never call `.Result()`, this can lead to a lot of problems, when possible use `await` keyword or use GetAwaiter().GetResult() instead of `.Result()`

Comment: Just to rule out basic mistakes, did you verify that the URL of the API and http verb being used in code and postman are the same?